# How to address "communication failure" on Android KeyStore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, encryption, android-keystore

I'm using Android KeyStore for storing cryptographic keys. I recently found out that for very few devices (all of them Android 10) an error is generated when trying to decrypt data using keys contained in the KeyStore.

The error appears when initilizing the cipher.

```
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, Base64.decode(ivString, Base64.NO_WRAP))
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(), spec) // Here I get the error.
```

where `getSecretKey()` is:

```
@Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, UnrecoverableEntryException::class, KeyStoreException::class)
private fun getSecretKey(): SecretKey {
    return (keyStore.getEntry(ALIAS, null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry).secretKey
}
```

The error I get is:

```
android.security.keystore.KeyStoreConnectException
Failed to communicate with keystore service

android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized (AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:256)
    android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit (AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:148)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider (Cipher.java:2980)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations (Cipher.java:2891)
    javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider (Cipher.java:2796)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider (Cipher.java:773)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.init (Cipher.java:1288)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.init (Cipher.java:1223)
mypackage.data.source.pass.storage.security.AesDecryptor.decryptData (AesDecryptor.kt:42)
```

Looking at the code of  `AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java` I see that the failure is related to `mKeyStore.begin()` returning `null`.

```
OperationResult opResult = mKeyStore.begin(
                mKey.getAlias(),
                purpose,
                true, // permit aborting this operation if keystore runs out of resources
                keymasterInputArgs,
                additionalEntropy,
                mKey.getUid());
        if (opResult == null) {
            throw new KeyStoreConnectException(); // LINE 256. This exception is thrown
        }
```

Any ideas?

NOTE: An interesting detail is that currently we are getting the key in the background thread. Before it was in the main thread and we never encountered the problem (even though we don't have big stats).

Comment: Given your note, it's most likely a problem with multithreading. The error mentions lack of initialization. Maybe you are using the value before the background thread finished initializing it? I think there is too little context in the question.

Comment: @Fureeish the initialization is done in the constructor, so it cannot be not-initilialized when I access it 
`init { initKeyStore() }`

Comment: @Fureeish it seems like the problem is related to a bug in Android 10: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147384380
which is related to multi-threading, but not a mistake on my implementation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems to be a bug in Android 10. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152240028
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147384380

Google engineers are working on it.